# Anaconda Navigator won't launch, download_api error (Windows 10)

Tags: windows, anaconda, navigator

Last night I ran a Windows update and this morning Anaconda Navigator hanged when I tried to launch it.  After googling I ran some updates in the Anaconda prompt:

```
conda update
conda update anaconda-navigator
```

And then when I tried to launch Anaconda Navigator from the prompt, I got this error:

```
2019-03-01 09:23:00,212 - ERROR download_api._get_url:416
Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\xxxx\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\anaconda_navigator\widgets\main_window.py", line 539, in setup
self.post_setup(conda_data=conda_data)
File "C:\Users\xxxx\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\anaconda_navigator\widgets\main_window.py", line 576, in post_setup
self.tab_home.setup(conda_data)
File "C:\Users\xxxx\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\anaconda_navigator\widgets\tabs\home.py", line 169, in setup
self.set_applications(applications, packages)
File "C:\Users\xxxx\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\anaconda_navigator\widgets\tabs\home.py", line 204, in set_applications
apps = self.api.process_apps(applications, prefix=self.current_prefix)
File "C:\Users\xxxx\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\anaconda_navigator\api\anaconda_api.py", line 888, in process_apps
versions=[vsdata.get('productVersion')],
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'get'
```

I use [Jupyter Notebook](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPython#Project_Jupyter) and [Spyder](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spyder_%28software%29) and this is causing me a major headache.

Answer (score 5):

There's another solution (not the best, but it works). Anaconda can't retrieve the [Visual Studio Code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visual_Studio_Code) version for any reason.

You need to replace line 888 in file *"C:\Users\xxxx\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\anaconda_navigator\api\anaconda_api.py"* from

```
versions=[vsdata.get('productVersion')]
```

to

```
versions=["1b8e8302e405050205e69b59abb3559592bb9e60"],
```

Answer (score 1):

As a [Ubuntu](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ubuntu_%28operating_system%29) user, it happened with me too. I used to remove anaconda-navigator and install it again through these commands:

```
conda remove anaconda-navigator
conda install anaconda-navigator
```

If it didn't work, check [the troubleshooting page](https://docs.anaconda.com/free/navigator/troubleshooting/) with other solutions.

Answer (score 0):

After lots of restarts and lots of googling I found a simple fix:

```
conda update navigator-updater
```

It works...for now

Answer (score 0):

For me it worked only when I'm connected to the Internet. Offline, it fails to start.

Answer (score 0):

Only reinstalling anaconda worked for me (I have completely removed and installed anaconda3)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/35483160)